# How to remove SSL for the Default web site in IIS6

Tags: iis-6, web-hosting

I have installed a self-signed SSL Certificate into IIS 6 using Internet Information Services (IIS) 6.0 Resource Kit Tools (iis60rkt.exe) for my Defult web site

Now I want to remove the self-signed SSL Certificate for Default web site How to do that? Please help

Answer (score 4):

1. Select **your Server** in IIS. ( *Not Default Website* )
2. In opened window select **Server Certificates**.
3. Select **your certificate**.
4. In right panel click **Remove**.
5. Click **Yes**.